# Appending the code onto "jsoninput.json" file in Server.MapPath using FileStream and StreamWriter

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

"jsonr" has been appended to from its original form `jsoninput.json`.

`jsoninput.json`:

> `[count:[{first:1,second:1,third:1},{first:2,second:2,third:2}]]`

I want to be able to save the changes made to "jsoninput.json" by appending the code into `jsonr` onto `jsoninput.json` in `Server.MapPath` using `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` as below:

```
jsonr="[count:[{first:1,second:2,third:3},{first:11,second:22,third:33},{first:111,second:222,third:333}]]"
using (FileStream fsAppend = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/jsoninput.json"), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fsAppend);
    sw.Write(jsonr);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    StreamWriter Stream = File.AppendText(Server.MapPath("~/jsoninput.json"),jsonr);
    Stream.Close();
    fsAppend.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JsonString.json` file contens before add new json array is below:

```
 {
 "data": [
          {
          "name": "Person 1",
          "email": "test@test.com",
          "address": {
          "address1": "my address 1",
          "address2": "my address 2"
        }
      },
    {
      "name": "Person 2",
      "email": "example@example.com",
      "address": {
        "address1": "my address 1",
        "address2": "my address 2"
          }
        }
      ]
 }
```

Target json array to add:

```
string jsonr="{
                count:[
                        {first:1,
                         second:2,
                         third:3
                        },      
                        {first:11,
                         second:22,
                         third:33
                        },
                        {first:111,
                         second:222,
                         third:333
                        }
                      ]
              }";
```

`C#` code to add `jsonr` to `JsonString.json`:

```
string jsonPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "JsonString.json");
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
var jsonrObject = JObject.Parse(jsonr)["count"];
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
string resultJson = o.Property("data").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("count", jsonrObject)).ToString();
```

> Code is tested

Comment: That would be great but I cannot download and install NewtonSoft. Json.net without errors.

Comment: Right click on your project, click `Manage NuGet Packages` -> Search `Newtonsoft.Json` and install.